# excel interop variable range

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm really new at this. I need to specify a range of continuous cells in a worksheet, of which I only know the first one.
Ordinarily, for a fixed number of cells, I use (as an example for 13 continuous cells):

```
Excel::Range^ er7 = Wsheet1->Range["H8:H20", Type::Missing];

er7->Formula = "=SUM(E8:G8)/3";
```

and it works.

Now, I want the last cell of the range (the H20) to be a function of the number of items listed in the worksheet. Something like, for instance,  `H8+k` (k being a known integer, of course).

Can you, PLEASE, help? THANK YOU

P.S. I'm coding in c++/cli but have borrowed from examples I've found in c#.

Answer (score 0):

=COUNTA(H8:H20) would give you the number of non-blank cells in the range. Is that what you mean by number of items listed?

**Edit:**

If you are saying that you have a known reference range (say cell "H8"), and a known number of rows (say r = 20) and/or columns (say c = 10) that would constitute your entire range, then you could use the Resize function. I'm not familiar with C++ but using Interop.Excel in C# the code would be:

```
er7 = xlApp.get_Range(ws.Range["H8", System.Type.Missing].Resize[r, c]);
```

Comment: What I mean to say is that the block of cells to which I want to insert that formula always starts at cell H8; but every time the worksheet is created the number of cell changes. That number is known, but I cannot write something like Excel::Range^ er7 = Wsheet1->Range["H8:H8 + 20", Type::Missing] because I get a generic run-time com exception.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

COUNT(B500:B585)+COUNTBLANK(B500:B585) would give you all the items in the range whether they are blank or not.

I am not sure the syntax for C# but possibly:

```
 rowLen = er7->rows->count;
 er7->Cells[rowLen - 1,1]->Formula = "=SUM(E8:G8)/3";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to count the number of cells for I know how many there are (n cells). I just want to be able to translate that into the code  that specifies the range. If I use a fixed range ("H8:H20") it will only work properly when the number of cells I want to apply the formula is exactly 13.

Answer (score 0):

It was in front of my eyes all the time. It wasn't even an Excel Interop problem. It was syntax. 
I said the number of cells involved in the range was known, as well as the initial one. Well, since the last cell was in the last row of the data, all that needed to be done was this:

```
int r = Wsheet1->UsedRange->Rows->Count;
Excel::Range^ er7 = Wsheet1->Range["G8:G"+r.ToString(), Type::Missing];
er7->Formula = "=SUM(E8:F8)/2";
```

Voilà.
Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Well done. BTW your code could be simplified to `Excel::Range^ er7 = Wsheet1->UsedRange->Columns["G:G"];`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I''ll try that.